# Java Builder with inheritance - type issue

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am trying to define a builder implementation which supports inheritance, and provides a clean interface to the client code.  However I'm hitting the 'incompatible types' issue on the `set()` methods.  This method allows the state of the buider to be set to that of a reference instance.

The following is a minimal example which demonstrates the error:

```
public class P 
{
    public P () {}
    protected P (Builder<? extends P,? extends Builder> builder) {}
    public static Builder<? extends P,? extends Builder> builder ()
    {
        return new Builder<> ();
    }
    public static class Builder<C extends P, B extends Builder<C,B>>
    {
        public B set (C c) { return (B) this ; }
        public C build () { return (C) new P (this) ; }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        P p0 = new A ();
        P p1 = A.builder ()
            .set (p0)        // error!
            .build ();
    }
}
```

Class `P` as the "buildee" defines a static inner `Builder` class obtained via a `builder()` factory method.  Since we must support derived classes, `Builder` is defined such that it remains fluent under derivation, and `builder()` is defined with bound generics to allow it to be overridden in derived classes.

The error on the use of `set()` is

> error: incompatible types:
>   `P` cannot be converted to `CAP#1` `.set (p0)`
>   where `CAP#1` is a fresh type-variable:
>       `CAP#1 extends P` from capture of `? extends P`

Now, the `Builder` as defined by `builder()` has its generic types defined by bounds.  They could not be defined as concrete types as this prevents the static function from being overriden in a derived type -- whereas generic bounds can be tightened in a subclass.  Is there a better way to obtain a builder instance without requiring the caller to specify generic types which should be implicit at that point?

The `Builder` definition of `C` is likewise bounded rather than absolute as it is expected that a derived class, say `Q`, will also derived from the base class's builder:

```
public class Q
extends P
{
    protected Q (Builder<? extends Q, ? extends Builder> builder)
    {
        super (builder);
    }
    public Builder<? extends Q, ? extends Builder> builder ()
    {
        return new Builder<> ();
    }
    public static class Builder<C extends Q, B extends Buider<C,B>>
    extends P.Builder<C,B>
    {
        @Override
        public B set (C instance)
        {
            super.set (instance);
            return (B) this;
        }
        @Override
        public C build ()
        {
            return new Q (this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this almost all works -- along with fields and fluent setters (not shown in minimal code).  At least appears to...  Only the `set()` method is causing an issue.

So is there a definition of `set()`, and/or `builder()` (or other parts), which will satisfy the compiler and support inheritance?

---

Just to add, that after trying various combinations, the only pattern that compiles and runs as expected is if the parameter of the builder's `set()` method is defined as the explicit class being built rather than the generic type `C`.

I had defined a Builder interface which defines the generic `set(C)`; initially this was just to enforce consistency.  However it now seems necessary to gives the explicitly-typed `set()` methods in the derived classes something to override.  Remains to be seen whether this is a genuine override, or if `P.builder().set(q)` would be allowed to call `Q::Builder::set(Q)` *(slicing!)*.

Comment: All these problems go away if you compose `P` into `Q` and write the builder for `P` to use the builder for `Q`.  While it would be common to use heritable builder code for an abstract `P`, maintaining a chain of builders for concrete subclasses sounds like something to avoid.

Comment: @scottb Unfortunately the chain of concrete classes already exist, with constructors of ever increasing parameter counts...

Comment: I've tested with generic builders and inheritance a year ago and created this [github repo](https://github.com/RovoMe/GenericBuilder) which also contains a further branch for defining the return type via generics. Some IDEs had some difficulties analyzing the code though on console the code compiles and also executes.

Answer (score 1):

If you try `super` instead of `extends`, your initial example will compile:

```
public static Builder<? super P, ? extends Builder> builder() {
    return new Builder<>();
}
```

Here is the full example as I have it:

```
public class P {
    public P() {
    }

    protected P(Builder<? extends P, ? extends Builder> builder) {
    }

    public static Builder<? super P, ? extends Builder> builder() {
        return new Builder<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P p0 = new P();
        P p1 = P.builder()
                .set(p0)        // no error!
                .build();
    }

    public static class Builder<C extends P, B extends Builder<C, B>> {

        public B set(C c) {
            return (B) this;
        }

        public C build() {
            return (C) new P(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for it not to compile is that you can read subtypes via `extends`, but only write to subtypes via `super`.

Even though this page is about Kotlin types, it is quite enlightening also about Java wildcard type arguments:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

It describes the typical behaviour of `extends` in Java:

> The wildcard type argument ? extends E indicates that this method
>   accepts a collection of objects of E or some subtype of E, not just E
>   itself. This means that we can safely **read** E's from items
>   (elements of this collection are instances of a subclass of E), **but
>   cannot write to it** since we do not know what objects comply to that
>   unknown subtype of E.

By the way: in order for your class Q to compile for me I have needed to re-write it to:

```
public class Q
        extends P {

    protected Q(Builder<? extends Q, ? extends Builder> builder) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public static class Builder<C extends Q, B extends Builder<C, B>>
            extends P.Builder<C, B> {

        @Override
        public B set(C instance) {
            super.set(instance);
            return (B) this;  // unchecked cast
        }


        @Override
        public C build() {
            return (C) new Q(this); // unchecked cast
        }
    }
}
```

The `builder` method in class `Q` cannot have the `override` annotation. There are two unchecked casts though.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the `extends` to `super` in static function `P.builder()` prevents the corresponding definition of `Q.builder()`.